# C# Xml Encoding

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, xmldocument, xmlnode

I'm freaking out with `C#` and XmlDocuments right now.

I need to parse XML data into another XML but I can't get special characters to work.

I'm working with XmlDocument and XmlNode.

What I tried so far: 
    - `XmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");`
    - `XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(outputDir + "systems.xml", Encoding.UTF8);`

What I know for sure:
    - The input XML is also `UTF-8` 
    - The "InnerText" value is encoded without replacing the characters

Here is some code (not all... way to much code):

```
XmlDocument newXml = new XmlDocument();
newXml = (XmlDocument)systemsTemplate.Clone();
newXml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
newXml.SelectSingleNode("systems").RemoveAll();
foreach(XmlNode categories in       exSystems.SelectNodes("root/Content/Systems/SystemLine"))
        {
            XmlNode categorieSystemNode = systemsTemplate.SelectSingleNode("systems/system").Clone();
            categorieSystemNode.RemoveAll();
            XmlNode importIdNode = systemsTemplate.SelectSingleNode("systems/system/import_id").Clone();
            string import_id = categories.Attributes["nodeName"].Value;
            importIdNode.InnerText = import_id;
            categorieSystemNode.AppendChild(importIdNode);
            [way more Nodes which I proceed like this]
        } 
 newXml.SelectSingleNode("systems").AppendChild(newXml.ImportNode(categorieSystemNode, true));
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(outputDir + "systems.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        newXml.Save(writer);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
```

But what I get is this as an example:

```
<intro>&lt;p&gt;Whether your project [...]</intro>
```

Instead of this:

```
<intro><p>Whether your project [...] </p></intro>
```

I do have other non-html tags in the XML so please don't provide HTML-parsing solutions :/ 
I know I could replace the characters with `String.Replace()` but that's dirty and unsafe (and slow with around 20K lines).

I hope there is a simpler way of doing this.

Kind regards, 
Eriwas

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code contains lots of things that aren't relevant and it's not clear where the issue is.  As a possible hint, you will get this issue if you set `InnerText` with XML content, it's nothing to do with text encoding. If you want a 'simpler way', I'd strongly suggest ditching `XmlDocument` for LINQ to XML.

Comment: Have you tried `InnerXml` instead of `InnerText`?

Answer (score 0):

The main propose of `XmlDocument` is to provide an easy way to work with XML documents while making sure the outcome is a well formed document.

So, using `InnerText` as in your example, you let the framework encode the string and properly insert it into that document. Whenever you read that same value, it will be decoded and returned to you exactly as your original string.

But, if you want to add an XML fragment anyways, you should stick with `InnerXml` or `ImportNode`. You must be aware that could lead to a more complex document structure, and you probably would like to avoid that.

As a third possibility, you can use the `CreateCDataSection` to add a `CDATA` and add your text there.

You definitely should be away from treating that XML document as a string by trying `Replace` things; stick with the framework and you'll be ok.